# Link from Oracle to SQL Server can't create view

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle10g, database-link

using oracle 10 i have a link to sql server. I have a query (below) that runs fine as just as a select statment but when i use it to create a view (the view is created succsesfully but when i try to view the data in the view in sql developer) i get a

database 'linkname' does not support ROWIDs in this context

Is the issue the subselects where I am combining multiple rows in one table into multiple columns?

```
  SELECT
    upper(cus."cus_last_name")  AS lname,
    upper(cus."cus_first_name") AS fname,
    upper(cus."cus_initial")    AS minitial,
    upper(cus."maiden_name")   AS olname,
    pt."cus_dob"               AS dob,
    pt."cus_id"              AS id,
    (
      SELECT
        cus_inst_key."cus_key_value"
      FROM
        "cus_inst_key"@linkname cus_inst_key
      WHERE
        cus_inst_key."cus_id"             = cus."cus_id"
      AND cus_inst_key."cus_key_cd"       = 1
    ) AS CUSALTID,
    (
      SELECT
        pcus_inst_key."cus_key_value"
      FROM
        "cus_inst_key"@linkname cus_inst_key
      WHERE
        cus_inst_key."cus_id"             = cus."cus_id"
      AND cus_inst_key."cus_key_cd"       = 2
     ) AS CUSALTID2,
    (
      SELECT
        cus_inst_key."cus_key_value"
      FROM
        "cus_inst_key"@linkname cus_inst_key
      WHERE
        cus_inst_key."cus_id"             = cus."cus_id"
      AND cus_inst_key."cus_key_cd"       = 3
    ) AS CUSALTID3,
    (
      SELECT
        cus_inst_key."cus_key_value"
      FROM
        "cus_inst_key"@linkname cus_inst_key
      WHERE
        cus_inst_key."cus_id"             = cus."cus_id"
      AND cus_inst_key."cus_key_cd"       = 4
    ) AS CUSALTID4
  FROM
    "cus"@linkname cus;
```

thanks for any help.

---

the view actually is created ok i just can't use the data tab in sql developer for some reason.